# Awk a range of numbers from a specific column in a csv file

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to print the rows from a csv file that have a third column value greater than `-39`. I have tried using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) but have not been able to get the command to work:

```
awk -F "," '{$3 > -39}' momenttensors.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your comparison inside an action block. You want it in the pattern section. Remove the <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>.

```
awk -F, '$3 > -39' momenttensors.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk -F, '$3 > -39' momenttensors.csv
```

You need the test part. `{}` this is an action part.